# ARRAY_CONSTRAIN w/ IMPORTRANGE ISSUE

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm using the below formula in one of my sheets.

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(SORT(SORTN( FILTER({Master!$B$4:B145},Master!$BZ$4:BZ145="x", ROW(Master!$B$4:B145)>MATCH(A6,Master!$B$4:B145,0)+2),6,,5,4),5,4)),7,4)

It works fine as it is above within the same workbook/file. Once I try to incorporate the IMPORTRANGE formula into it (to draw the data from another workbook/file), like:

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN((SORT(SORTN( FILTER({IMPORTRANGE("1L-izrDuI7SaF3THCoSeO3jjnZIsMBzpGWEHCtZdv57k","Master!$B$4:B145"),IMPORTRANGE("1L-izrDuI7SaF3THCoSeO3jjnZIsMBzpGWEHCtZdv57k","Master!$BO$4:BO145")},IMPORTRANGE("1L-izrDuI7SaF3THCoSeO3jjnZIsMBzpGWEHCtZdv57k","Master!$BZ$4:BZ145")="x", ROW(IMPORTRANGE("1L-izrDuI7SaF3THCoSeO3jjnZIsMBzpGWEHCtZdv57k","Master!$B$4:B145"))>MATCH(A6,IMPORTRANGE("1L-izrDuI7SaF3THCoSeO3jjnZIsMBzpGWEHCtZdv57k","Master!$B$4:B145"),0)+2),6,,5,4),5,4)),7,4)

I get this error:

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 144. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

I've done everything I can think of but nothing works. Can anyone help?

Cheers,

C

[Test 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yo6hfCAcsA0dPfaeSlaiAOS1M93SzSzy8mD7m2gwmV4/edit#gid=0)

[Test 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJaqC3p-uChUNy8R41cJ5c82cTtLmYqzr0Pu10OZDpc/edit#gid=1285760248)

Comment: It would help if you could recreate this scenario in 2 test sheets (using *realistic*-demo data) and share them with us to troubleshoot it directly.

Comment: I added links to test sheets

Comment: Thanks!   Can I limit the number of answers I get like in the other formula which didn't work?  Also can you pull a second column in at the same time?

Comment: Also on my actual sheet the two columns (A&B) are C and bZ. Not sure how to incorporate that into what you have here.

Comment: Added the original formula(slightly modified) in *Cell_D8*. do test it out...

Answer (score 0):

*Added a formula in your `Test2` sheet:*

```js
=let(Σ,importrange("spreadsheet-ID","Master!A:B"),
     col1_,index(Σ,,1), col2_, index(Σ,,2),
     filter(col1_,col2_="x",sequence(rows(col1_))>xmatch(A1,col1_)))
```

[image]